# What does "こうと思っていたことを思い出した" mean?

Tags: meaning

Context:
今日は午前中家の掃除をして、本を読んだり日記を見直していました。
元々は一日家でのんびりしようと思っていたけど、午後、**前から**時間があったら近くのお寺に引っ越しの挨拶をしに行こう**と思っていた**こと**を思い出した**ので行きました。
お寺は閉まっていたので近くの神社に行ってきました。

I think there's a little complex structure in that sentence.

1. Does "こうと思っていたことを思い出した" mean "I recalled an earlier thought"?
2. Does "前から" modify "と思っていた"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Does "こうと思っていたことを思い出した" mean "I recalled an earlier thought"?

Yes. Just to clarify, こう is not a standalone word but is part of 行こう, the volitional form of 行く. Don't split a word like that. It's like saying just the "oing" part of "going".

> 2. Does "前から" modify "と思っていた"?

Yes.

Here's a full translation:

> 元々は一日家でのんびりしようと思っていたけど、
> I originally planned to relax at home all day, but
>
> 午後、～ことを思い出した
> in the afternoon, I recalled that ～
>
> **前から**時間があったら近くのお寺に引っ越しの挨拶をしに行こうと思っていた
> I had been thinking **(from before)** about visiting a nearby temple to [give a moving-in greeting](https://hanko-seal.com/archives/2068) when I had the time,
>
> ので行きました。
> so I went out (to the temple).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I wasn't quite sure what "引っ越しの挨拶" means before, and after reading your translation I realized it is give a "moving-in greeting" to a nearby temple.